# How do I install another desktop on ubuntu Gnome

Tags: 16.04, gnome, kde

I am currently using Gnome 3.20.4 I want to switch to KDE plasma but I dont want to reinstall the whole system just for that. Would there be a way to switch and keep my files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way, but I should start with a warning:

It is easy to install another desktop environment and to switch between them at the login screen - they are often called 'sessions'. But there can be problems, that the two desktop environments interfere with each other, and there are duplicate application programs, which will clutter the menus. And finally, it is very difficult to reverse the operation, to get only one single clean desktop environment again. So you should backup your current system if you want to get back.

Install KDE with

```
sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

See this link for more details,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE)